# Can you get reputation when people follow links to questions or SO sites?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, badges, permalink, linked-questions

One thing I really like about StackOverflow is how professional the responses can be. I like the dedicated sub sites that are being created too.

1. Could there be an Evangelist badge?
2. Could we get points when people follow your links to sites or questions?

I have committed to other sites like [Tridion](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38335/tridion?referrer=LmyvmFVinDqNn9xqeeO2NA2). Those sites recognize when I refer people, so do ALL StackExchange sites do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Like the [Announcer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/74/announcer) (bronze), [Booster](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/75/booster) (silver) and [Publicist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/76/publicist) (gold) badges? These are common to all sites.
2. Why? Reputation from upvotes is enough - many people who will come from a link will likely end up voting. Getting reputation just from traffic is something that will only help popular bloggers, not other members of the community.

Comment: Those are great points! Thank you for proving why Stack Overflow is a fantastic resource. I hope others find this question and your answer helpful too.

Comment: To answer "why?", it would be good to know that my announcing is paying off with folks following my advice. For questions, I think I need to modify my out going messages to say "come check out this great question and vote it up if you agree".